# Python pyPFD2 PDF crop pages and merge into single page

Tags: python, pypdf

Trying to crop a couple of PDF pages and merge them into a single role style page.
I need to remove the heather and the footer of each page and create a role style single page

```
import PyPDF2

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF2.pdf import PageObject

reader = PdfFileReader('/Users/kic/Desktop/test.pdf','r')
writer = PdfFileWriter()

### find Total Height of file ###

numpages = reader.getNumPages() ## get number of pages
Height = reader.getPage(0).mediaBox.getHeight() ## get height of title page
Height = Height + 482 * (reader.getNumPages()-2) ## add number of height crop pages

### create new single role page ###

Single_page = PageObject.createBlankPage(None, reader.getPage(0).mediaBox.getWidth(),    Height)
### add first title page without croping ###

Single_page.mergeTranslatedPage(reader.getPage(0),0,Height-reader.getPage(0).mediaBox.getHeight(),False)

### loop through all pages from page 2 until last page ###

n=1
for i in range(reader.getNumPages()-1):
    
    i=n
    page = reader.getPage(i)

    page.cropBox.setUpperLeft((0,556))
    page.cropBox.setUpperRight((page.mediaBox.getWidth(),556))
    page.cropBox.setLowerLeft((0,74))
    page.cropBox.setLowerRight((page.mediaBox.getWidth(),74))

    Single_page.mergeTranslatedPage(page,0,482*(numpages-1-n),False)

    #writer.addPage(page) ##to see the result of the cropped pages without merging
    n = n+1

writer.addPage(Single_page)

output = open('/Users/kic/Desktop/testrcrop.pdf','wb')
writer.write(output)
output.close()
```

for some reason it is not cropping, its merging the pages into 1 page, but the heather and footer go on top of each other.
However if I don't merge into 1 page and just write the cropped pages into a PDF file with several pages they show up cropped.

Answer (score 0):

You should translate the cropped area and set its mediabox new bounds for the position they'll occupy in the new page.
**You translate relative to current position and crop by absolute values.**

According with the[`mergeTranslatedPage()` documentation](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PageObject.html#pypdf._page.PageObject.mergeTranslatedPage), it has been deprecated, and you should use `add_transformation()` and `merge_page()` instead.

The line `y_translation = total_height - upper_bound` calculates how much you need to translate each page considering the bounds of the cropped area in relation to the previous page you inserted on the new page.

For example:
*You have 4 pages with a height of 800, and from page 2 to the end they'll be cropped at 600 and 200, your new page should have a height of 2000.

If the top of your first page is at 800, you'll have to translate it by 1200, and crop it on 2000 and 1200. The second page's cropped area top is at 600 and must be at 1200 (2000 - 800), so you need to translate it by 600 and crop it on 1200 and 800. And so on...*

1. *T=1200, U=2000, B=1200*
2. *T=600, U=1200, B=800*
3. *T=200, U=800, B=400*
4. *T=-200, U=400, B=0*

```
from PyPDF2 import PageObject, PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter, Transformation

# Define the crop bounds for pages other than the first page
CROP_Y_TOP = 556
CROP_Y_HEIGHT = 482

# Set the input and output file paths
input_path = r"input.pdf"
output_path = r"output.pdf"

# Open the input and output files in binary read and write mode
with open(input_path, "rb") as input_file, open(output_path, "wb") as output_file:
    # Create a PdfFileReader object for the input file
    reader = PdfFileReader(input_file)
    # Create a PdfFileWriter object for the output file
    writer = PdfFileWriter()

    # Calculate the total height of the output page
    total_height = reader.getPage(0).mediabox.height + (CROP_Y_HEIGHT * (reader.getNumPages() - 1))

    # Create a blank page with the calculated total height
    single_page = PageObject.create_blank_page(
        pdf=None,
        width=reader.getPage(0).mediabox.width,
        height=total_height
    )

    # Loop through all pages of the input document
    for i in range(reader.getNumPages()):
        # Get the current page
        page = reader.getPage(i)
        original_mediabox = reader.getPage(i).mediaBox

        # Determine the upper and lower bounds for the crop
        upper_bound = original_mediabox.height if i == 0 else CROP_Y_TOP
        lower_bound = 0 if i == 0 else CROP_Y_TOP - CROP_Y_HEIGHT

        # Calculate the translation to apply to the page
        y_translation = total_height - upper_bound

        # Create a transformation object with the calculated translation
        transformation = Transformation().translate(ty=y_translation)
        # Apply the transformation to the page
        page.add_transformation(transformation)

        # Update the page media box with the new bounds
        page.mediabox.lower_left = (0, lower_bound + y_translation)
        page.mediabox.upper_right = (original_mediabox.width, upper_bound + y_translation)

        print(f"T={y_translation}\tU={upper_bound + y_translation}\tL={lower_bound + y_translation}")

        # Merge the transformed page onto the output page
        single_page.merge_page(page)

        # Decrease the total height by the height of the current page
        total_height -= upper_bound

    # Add the output page to the writer
    writer.addPage(single_page)

    # Write the output file
    writer.write(output_file)
```